# Best Desktop Environment for Steam

Tags: unity, games, steam, desktop-environments

I think my question is rather simple. What is the best Desktop Environment for use of Steam and games. I have had many problems with Unity in the past and there must be a better Environment. What is the SteamOS Desktop? Should I be using that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/about/

Comment: @DnrDevil I understand the SteamOS is downloadable and I believe it uses Gnome, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Try KDE. It has best resources out there.

Comment: `Best` is very subjective and off topic here as no `right` answer can be given, please see http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask Of course a light desktop (LXDE, XFCE, openbox)  has better performance (uses less graphics ram / system ram) but the difference is negligible on anything but old computers and laptops. A modern environment (Unity, Gnome, KDE) will work best on a powerful system due to optimization. Side note, Steam runs better for me on Ubuntu Unity than Steam OS.

Comment: @riashat.rafat Thats just not true, at all !!!! You are saying KDE uses less resources than LXDE or XFCE, no, you are wrong. KDE is one of the `modern` desktops, that uses similar resources to Windows or Unity or Gnome, about 512MB of RAM.

Comment: For some games, and because I did not want to get rid of Unity entirely I installed `gnome-session-flashback` to log in to a lighter DE having not too many new dependencies.

Comment: @mark kirby, when did I said KDE uses less resources than LXDE or XFCE. I said KDE has the best resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what version of unity do you have ? Second if you think a light weight desktop enviroment will make your game run faster than, you can install the Lubuntu xubuntu environment inside ubuntu. Lubuntu is the most light weight. You can use their environment instead of unity. However, unity will still be on the system, just not in use. 
I currently have xubuntu (second lightest weight) , and am running it alongside unity, which is unstable, but really beautiful. If you prefer completely getting rid of unity and want to run the LXDE desktop,you’ll have to do some extra steps.

Try as many as you want. 
Different environments commands

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install Lubuntu-desktop
```